# How to check if a variable is categorical with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

I have an **R** data frame and some of the variables are categorical. For example sex is "male" or "female" and "do you smoke" is 0 or 1. Others  variables instead are continuous. 
I would like to know if there is any way to decide if a variable is categorical or not and in case compute its frequencies.

I think in my case a good test would be to check if the variable takes less than k=4 values.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `is.factor`?

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `sapply(DF, function(x) !(length(levels(factor(x))) == length(as.character(x))))`

Comment: try: 1) ```str(mydata)``` to see the actual data types of your data. 2) ```table(mydata$variable)``` to see the frecuency of each variable. 3) another option is to use: ```summary(mydata)``` to get a general idea of your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you should use factors for categorical variables, you can find the unique values in a vector `x` with `unique`, and count them:

```
length(unique(x))
```

Comment: You have to be careful using this method as it also counts missing values, `NA`, as a unique value. That's not always what you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip Jason, but in case would just be enough to add the level from 4 to 5 ?

Comment: @Donbeo That is correct.  Any number of NA values will count as one extra unique value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `class(dataframe$variable)` to know the class of a variable within a data frame as well as determine whether the variable is a factor or not.